# Showing the integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x(x+p)}\,dx$ is convergent for $p$ greater than $-1$.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Can someone help me why this is true:

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x(x+p)}\,dx = \frac{1}{p}\int_1^\infty\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+p}\right)dx$$

Comment: Is this partial fractions?

Comment: Your partial fraction is correct.. Your integral is equivalent to $\ln(x) - \ln(x + p) = \ln \big(\frac{x}{x + p} \big) \rvert_{1}^{\infty}$ Can you see why the statement might be true now? Can you see why $p$ _must be greater_ than $-1$?

Comment: so this indeed partial fractions?

Comment: Yes, you should start by finding the partial fraction decomposition of $\frac1{x(x+p)}$.

Comment: Note that $p=0$ is a special case with $p\gt-1$ for which the decomposition does not work, so that case needs to be tackled separately.

Answer (score 0):

Given that partial fraction decomposition, we have that a primitive for
$$ \frac{1}{x(x+p)}=\frac{1}{p}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+p}\right)$$
is given by:
$$ F(x)=\frac{1}{p}\,\log\left(\frac{x}{x+p}\right) $$
and such a function is bounded on $[1,+\infty)$ and converging to zero iff $p>-1$.